# Facebook sharing without any dialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sharer, android-facebook

Is it possible to share facebook stat from my app instantly without any dialog? This is because I don't want the user to edit the post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "Facebook stat"?

Comment: i meant sharing in facebook. i'm sorry, is it a wrong term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by using Facebook Login and then making Graph API calls to share links, photos, etc.

Make sure people have clear sharing experiences, though, and that the app follows Platform Policies wrt not surprising people / etc.

Comment: Do you have a link to a quick sample code for that, sir?

Comment: Is it possible to do? Facebook sharing with ShareDialog?